# Monitor for multimedia and programming

Tags: gaming, monitors

What would you recommend for daily, heavy use monitor? It'll be used mainly for programming, with breaks for gaming (grpahics GeForce GTX 960 4GB) and good series/films. Important are:

- Resolution: HD, WUXGA or WQHD (1080p - 1440p)
- 24 - 27 inch
- Good color quality with evenly distributed back-light
- Reliable - my current Eizo lit alredy 27000 hours with nothing but one bad pixel, that's the lifespan I'd expect

I found Eizo EV2450-BK and Dell U2515H to fit my requirements (that's also price range +/- 100$). What do you think you'd buy?

[EDIT]
Exact price up to 450$

Comment: 27,000 hours usage is going on 10 years, assuming 8 hours/day usage. That's... on the limits of credible, and certainly very difficult to find these days.

Comment: That's the actual number when I navigate the menu->information in the Eizo FlexScan S1901 I use from 8 years. Probably it counts screen saver, though 8 hours a day sounds like actual usage anyway ;)

Comment: Look for monitors that come with colour and consistency reports. My Dell 2715q did - tho it's outside your specifications for resolution... It's UHD. Also a precise price range would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eizos are pretty much the rolls royce of monitors. They make the best and terribly pricey monitors for graphics professionals and their build quality and warranties kind of match that.

That said, my sensible go to brand for monitors is dell.

I'm going to suggest an IPS display (for excellent colour *quality*) and factory caliberation (which means the panel ought to be consistent, and of good quality. 1440p seems to be a happy medium. I'd go with the Dell U2515H in this case.

Dell's got excellent build quality as far as their P series monitors go, and like my p2715q, its factory caliberated (which includes checks for consistant brightness, colour quality and so on). It also has an *excellent* built in stand allowing for a full range of motion (which is awesome!) on vertical height and rotation, as well as some tilt.

Its the 'closest' option to your eizo I can think of, and I've generally had great experiences with their monitors

Answer (score 0):

I think you're definitely going to want a monitor with LED backlighting, like the [Acer G257HL BMIDX](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824009720&nm_mc=AFC-C8Junction&cm_mmc=AFC-C8Junction-PCPartPicker,%20LLC-_-na-_-na-_-na&cm_sp=&AID=10446076&PID=3938566&SID=). At ~125.00, who cares how long it lasts? Everything else about it meets your spec, and I have good experiences with Acer monitors in general.

I would personally not ask the GTX 960 to perform at 1440p, so there's that, too.

Comment: When I got my 4k monitor, I found my GeForce 660 did 1440p fine.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, with all due respect, that is an anecdotal experience very far out of line with the reality of modern gaming. I own twin GTX 760s and a 1080p screen, and there are definitely struggles with vRAM and bandwidth in that setup. The 960 actually has less bandwidth and half the bus of the 760, and all the special tricks and extra vRAM in the world just can't fix that. Benchmarks show the 960 hitting above its spec weight for sure, but if it's not hitting solid 60fps marks across the board I'm not telling someone it's "good" for that resolution.

Comment: As a final note, it's not like I personally care about 60fps. It's just that I've found that when I espouse my personal opinion that 30+ fps is acceptable to me, most people find that standard extremely low. I would wager your experience is probably due to overclocking, playing lower end games, simply having lower standards like I do, or some combination thereof. In general, the assumption goes that a card is "good" at a given resolution if and only if it can hit 60fps average at some arbitrary definition of "max settings," at least in the minds of the majority of people I've worked with.

Comment: Factory OCed currentish games based on Nvidia's recommended settings

Comment: This was last year. I upgraded to a 980ti after that.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There you go then. Nvidia takes resolution into account for recommended settings. Would be interesting to see just how different the settings would be on 1080 vs 1440 if you still have the card laying around.

Comment: I sold it off to someone who needed a 'temporary' card. He ended up selling his 760 cause apparently my 660 was cooler, quieter and good enough ;p. *Great* card that, and I'd still be using it if I hadn't gone 4k,

Comment: The 660 and 760 were both great cards. My SLI setup, OCd, beats the 780ti in some games, like Witcher 3.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the [wirecutter's picks for best 27 inch monitor](http://thewirecutter.com/reviews/best-27-inch-monitor/), they've suggested the p2715H.

I'm a firm beliver in higher pixel density for working on text and graphics, but size has a quality on its own. 27 inches to me is 'ideal' for working on a single screen at my typical working distances (I use dual screens, but context switch, or move back a little).

The rest of the features of the 2415H is true here - factory colour caliberation and consistancy checks, and the same very flexible. Its got thin bezels and its a good, solid workhorse monitor if you have the deskspace. I'd note many people, including [Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-ips-lcd-revolution/) use one or more 27" monitors.

I'd consider the P2715Q a step up - when Ihad a 660, I was gaming at 1440p and doing many other things at 4k. Its worth a look as well.